# Flutter Using Form in Multiple Screens "Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree" Error

Tags: forms, flutter, key

I create a login page with Form for the key part i use "GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey();" It's working fine no problem. After login in a page I want to create a popup screen and I make everything like I make in the login page. Unfortunately I get this "Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree" error. I tried many things I saw on the web but none of them worked. My key is not static, not final. Also I tried pushReplacement for the login page but it's also not working. I am just trying to use Form in different pages in app what does not have any connections each other.

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  final TextEditingController emailContoller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordContoller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => LoginCubit(
              emailContoller,
              passwordContoller,
              _formKey,
            ),
        child: BlocConsumer<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is LoginComplete) {
              CacheManager.instance.addCacheItem(
                  '${state.loginResultModel.userID}', state.loginResultModel);
              state.navigate(context);
            } else if (state is LoginError) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.message)));
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return buildBackground(context, state);
          },
        ));
  }

  Background buildBackground(BuildContext context, LoginState state) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      
      child: Stack(children: [
        Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidateMode: autovalidateMode(state),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "LOGIN",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                //TextFormFields and buttons....
```

Popup has the same implementation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing the same `_formKey` to `LoginCubit()` so in this case you are using the same `GlobalKey()` in different place.

create two separate `GlobalKey()` and use them in two place.

`GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();`
`GlobalKey<FormState> _cubitFormKey = GlobalKey();`

and now use `_formKey` to `Form()` and pass `_cubitFormKey` to `LoginCubit()`